# Getters naming convention

Tags: php, naming-conventions, standards

I understand the traditional naming convention for getter methods:

```
getName();

getAddress();

getAge();
```

But i dont understand why.  I would rather just use the property name as the method as in the following example:

```
class Person
{
    private $name;

    private $address;

    private $age;

    public function __construct($name, $address, $age)
    {
      $this->name = name;
      $this->address = address;
      $this->age = age;
    }

    public function name()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function address()
    {
        return $this->address;
    }

    public function age()
    {
        return $this->age;
    }
}
```

This makes code more fluent to me

i.e.  $person->address()

But i get pulled up on code reviews when doing this for not using proper naming conventions.

Is there anything fundamentally wrong with not using get/set prefixes ?

Comment: I assume its php, but you better add appropriate tag to your question. Naming conventions are very different for different languages

Comment: What if you want to create an empty object and set attributes after the fact - you don't always have all the data at the point of instantiation to set all the attributes in the constructor (an order object for instance, you'll create it and store the data before you know whether Payment was successful or not).

Answer (score 0):

Generally it's good for methods to contain a verb. This way the method's name is more self explanatory.

More info and Source: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.naming.php